# integrating exponential with power of trigonometric functions

Tags: exponential-function, trigonometric-integrals

I'm stuck with the bellow integral and couldn't find any solution, If anyone has an idea how to continue I'll be very grateful.

(1)\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{a\cdot\sin2\theta+b\cdot\cos(\theta-\mu)}d\theta \end{equation}

I know that

(2)
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{a\cdot\sin\theta+b\cdot\cos\theta}d\theta={2\pi I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}$$

but couldn't find any way to get from (1) to (2)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you get this? What led to this?

Comment: compound distribution of 2 standard normal distribution and Von-Mises distribution.

Comment: Have you tried a CAS, like Wolfram Alpha, for example?

Comment: Yes, didn't help me